# FTP address of Drupal site and migration between dev and prod

Tags: drupal, ftp

I am learning Drupal now and I have some questions regarding migration :

1) I know this is a stupid question but I have a Drupal site that I need to update. I can access the admin menu aso but I don't have the ftp address hosting the site. I received a datasheet but it is not mentionned. Where can I find it ?

2) What is the easiest solution to migrate the development site to the production site ? I have the Backup and Migrate module so I can use it for the database but I also need to backup the files on the ftp server... But as mentionned I don't have the address.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you don't know the FTP adress, you just can ask it to your host
2. I don't realy know if it's the cleaniest solution, but when i have to migrate an Drupal solution, i make a export of my DB, and i edit the configuration file.
   if you are not sure of you, you can deploy all your drupal files on the new serveur, you process to the install & you import the database after.

still check there is no configuration on the database

Comment: If you haven't accessed FTP, most likely that you don't have any modifications done. You can hardly get the site working in new host by downloading fresh files from drupal.org and placing them correctly (sites/all/modules , sites/all,themes are modules and theme directories). Then, download db backup to new server, import it and make changes to settings.php (sites/default/settings.php). 

If your site is example.com, in most cases, example.com (port 21) is the default ftp host (ftp.example.com - may be).